# Convolution bound for $L^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis

I wish to show that

$$\Vert f * g \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}^2 \leq \Vert f * f \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})} \cdot \Vert g * g \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})},$$

for all $f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

Here is what I've got so far:

\begin{align*}
\Vert f * g \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}^2 &= \int_{\mathbb{T}} \vert (f * g)(x) \vert^2 dx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{T}} \left\vert \int_{\mathbb{T}} f(x-y)g(y)dy \right\vert^2dx\\
&\leq \iint_{\mathbb{T}^2} \vert f(x-y)g(y) \vert^2dydx\\
&\leq \left(\iint_{\mathbb{T}^2} \vert f(x-y) \vert^2dydx\right) \cdot \left(\iint_{\mathbb{T}^2} \vert g(y) \vert^2 dydx\right)\\
&= \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}^2 \cdot \Vert g \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}^2
\end{align*}

This seems pretty close to what I want but is not quite the desired result. Can someone give me a hint on how to proceed or another approach to try?

Comment: Do you know Plancherel's theorem?  If you hit this with the Fourier transform, it reduces to Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Nate's comment, by Plancherel's Identity and Cauchy-Schwarz, we have

\begin{align}
\|f*g\|_2^2&=\|\widehat{f*g}\|_2^2=\|\hat f\hat g\|_2^2\leq\|\hat f\|_4^2\|\hat g\|_4^2=\|\hat f^2\|_2\|\hat g^2\|_2\\&=\|\widehat{f*f}\|_2\|\widehat{g*g}\|_2=\|{f*f}\|_2\|{g*g}\|_2.
\end{align}

Comment: Does this also hold for $L^1(\mathbb{T})$?